# Speed issue in handsontable in mozila

Tags: handsontable

I am facing speed issue problem in handsontable in mozilla browser. Whenever I am writing anything in cell then press "Enter" key to go to next cell then it is taking around 3-5 seconds to move to the next cell. I am facing this speed problem when there are so many records in a sheet.

Please help me out from this situation. To see this problem, you can go on following:

http://www.promact.semanticexcel.com/

And login with following details:

username: test
password: test

and then open "LSA_Output_2nd.txt" sheet and then try to work with this sheet then you will notice speed issue. Please have a look and let me know if any solution you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't actually log into your test site, but your problem seems like a common one. Hansontable re-renders the whole table on any cell change. The best way to work around this is to limit the height of the table, then only visible rows will be rendered. See the demo page on scrolling: http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html

However, if you have many columns in your table, what you gain in editing performance, you lose in scroll performance, since all newly-visible rows need to be rendered when scrolling, which greatly worsens responsiveness. I'm yet to find a better alternative.